# Collection Iterator isn't returning every value

Tags: java, android, collections, iterator

I'm trying to return the sequence from a `Collection` and apply it to a `TextView`. When I set the text, only one value is set, the last of the sequence. When I print the sequence, to check it's working, everything prints correctly. As far as I can tell, I'm doing this right by saying while the iterator `hasNext()`, get `next()` and in this case, the name of the track. I've tried a few other ways to set the Collection properly, but after researching how to use an Iterator and Collection a little more, I always end up back with this method. What is it I'm missing?

```
public static String getTopTracks(String mArtistName) {
    String returnTopTracks = "";
    Collection<Track> top = Artist.getTopTracks(mArtistName, key);
    Iterator<Track> itr = top.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        returnTopTracks = itr.next().getName();
        System.out.println(returnTopTracks);
    }
    return returnTopTracks;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to return your top tracks as a Collection

```
public static Collection<String> getTopTracks(String mArtistName) {
    String returnTopTrack = "";
    Collection<Track> top = Artist.getTopTracks(mArtistName, key);
    Collection<String> returnTopTracks = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<Track> itr = top.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {          
        returnTopTrack = itr.next().getName();
        returnTopTracks.add(returnTopTrack);
        System.out.println(returnTopTrack);
    }
    return returnTopTracks;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted in regard to the `Iterator` or it's usage; it will call every object in the collection's getName() method. The fact that you're only returning the last one could, however, be a problem.

From your description it appears you would like to return all the Strings retured by each `Track`'s `getName()` method. You would need to return a `List` that you've placed all of them into, or perhaps just concatenate that `String` in the loop.